# How do you convert an XIB file that has two view objects to a StoryBoard ViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uiviewcontroller, xib

I am trying to get an XIB file to my storyboard. I have tried placing a viewcontroller on the storyboard and removing the view and adding the class of the xib file. However this only brings up the file and does not associate any of the other classes associated with it.

[image: XIB file with two view objects]

I figure since I am using the storyboard, I will like to keep it that way. How do I 'convert' this xib with all its outlets? Do I need to create viewcontrollers for each object view?

Any help is much appreciated. Been stuck for 2 days

Comment: Copy the views in the xib and paste them into your view controllers after removing their default views.

Comment: I tried adding both views to the view controller but then it states the classes associated can not be found. To be exact it states "unknown class "my class" in interface builder file.

Comment: Are the xibs in the same project that you have the storyboard in?

Comment: Yes they are in the same project

Comment: What is MyClass? Is that the class of one of the views that you had in the xib? I'm not sure why it wouldn't be able to find the class -- when I tried this with a custom UIView subclass in a xib, it pasted into the storyboard with no errors.

Comment: Yep, My Class is one of the views. I am not sure why. I went as far as to copy the files out of the current project, build it seperately and it worked. For this instance I have no clue